# Placing the like button of a fan page in the middle of a landing page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I wanted to know if it is possible to add the like button of a Facebook fan page(which is normally placed on the header of the page), as being  embedded inside a landing page. I know I can make use of the like button generator given by Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ , but I am after getting the like button of a fan page (which in reality is visually different than the like button that is generated at the above mentioned link). If indeed there is a way , please let me know. I welcome your suggestions.

Regards,
Ghulam Mustafa Majal

Answer (score 1):

You can place a like button to the Facebook Page inside the landing page by specifying the appropriate `href` or using the Like box (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/). For example, this Like button likes the Facebook Platform Page and can be pasted directly inside an iframe on a Page Tab:

`<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=191014414294211&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>`

Comment: Thank you for your response, the thing is I am looking like for a button similar to the like button given here http://socialmediaseo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/facebook-fan-page-like-button-image.jpg . I want to know if its possible to generate such buttons. Thank you, once again.